# Writing to files in HDFS from within spark transformation functions in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

My question is similar to an already answered question which is in scala and for reading files.

[Reading files dynamically from HDFS from within spark transformation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185692/reading-files-dynamically-from-hdfs-from-within-spark-transformation-functions)

I am aware of accumulators using them to return results to driver and writing to HDFS in driver. In our use case the output of each executor is large so I am looking for a way to write to HDFS within transformations in Java.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a graceful way to achieve this. Create a broadcast variable for hadoop configuration

```
Configuration configuration = JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(context).hadoopConfiguration();
Broadcast<SerializableWritable<Configuration>> bc = context.broadcast(new SerializableWritable<Configuration>(configuration));
```

Pass this broadcast variable to your transformation or action and get Hadoop file system using following code snippet:

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(bc.getValue().value());
```

Hoping this helps if somebody else is in the same boat.

Cheers !

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! : D you saved my time, thanks a lot, keep sharing! keep growing!

Answer (score 1):

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, byte[]> input = KafkaUtils.createJDQDirectStream(ssc, String.class, byte[].class,
        StringDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class, kafkaParams, Collections.singleton(topicName));

JavaPairDStream<String, byte[]> output = input.transformToPair(new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, byte[]>, JavaPairRDD<String, byte[]>>() {
    public JavaPairRDD<String, byte[]> call(JavaPairRDD<String, byte[]> stringJavaPairRDD) throws Exception {
        JavaSparkContext sc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(stringJavaPairRDD.context());
        stringJavaPairRDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://");
        return stringJavaPairRDD;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zhang for your response, appreciate you posting a method to do it. But in my case the intermediate data is not RDD and also we are not streaming data.

Comment: I finally picked some idea from your answer and was able to get solution. Posted as another answer ... thanks !