# Spark: How do I write individual row to S3 / HDFS as JPG

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have to write data as individual JPG files (~millions) from PySpark to an S3 bucket.

I tried multiple options:

setup: AWS EMR cluster and Jupyter notebook.

1. Create a boto3 client in 'foreach' method and write to S3 ==> too slow and inefficient as we open the client for every task.

```html
def get_image(y):
    res = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
    file_name = "./" +str(cid) + ".jpg"
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    file_name = str(cid) + ".jpg"
    client.put_object(Body=res.content, Bucket='test',  Key='out_images/'+file_name)

myRdd.foreach(get_image)
```

2. Write to local file system and run an "aws S3 copy" to S3 => Not clear on how to access this data if it is written to each individual worker node's volumes. Logged into worker nodes while the job is running but couldn't exactly find where the JPGs are written to.

```html
def get_image(y):
    res = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
    file_name = "./" +str(cid) + ".jpg"
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(res.content)

myRdd.foreach(get_image)
```

3. Write to HDFS and run an s3-dist-cp later. Probably most efficient but haven't had success with code yet. `I get path cannot be found exceptions`

```html
def get_image(y):
    res = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
    file_name = "hdfs://" +str(cid) + ".jpg"
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(res.content)

myRdd.foreach(get_image)
```

Can someone suggest a good approach to achieving this?

Comment: what if you partition by the number of rows and then you write to S3 this way? I suppose than you could use a script using boto3 to change the format of each file.
`rows = df.count()`,
`df.repartition(rows).write.avro('save-dir')`

Comment: I have 500 million images to be written. I don't see re-partitioning as an ideal solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 works great if the `foreach` is replaced with [foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.foreachPartition.html). After this change, only one client is created per partitition:

```python
def get_image(y_it):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    for y in y_it:
        img_url = ...
        cid = ...
        res = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
        file_name = str(cid) + ".jpg"
        client.put_object(Body=res.content, Bucket='test',  Key='out_images/'+file_name)

myRdd.foreachPartition(get_image)
```

Within the loop over `y_it`, the same client is reused.

Things can even become faster if [requests.Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)s are used for the http call as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491383/2129801). In this case, a single http session is created outsite of the loop over `y_it` (like the client) and then reused within the loop.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried it out for a sample set and it is definitely faster compared to approach 1. I am gonna try again on the full dataset. Just curious if this is the only way and I'd like to hear your thoughts on Approach 3.

Comment: I would stick to approach 1 as this approach can handle everything within Spark and you dont need any external tool. If you want to save data to HDFS within `get_image` you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46962688/2129801). Its written in Java, but the idea should also work in Python